# Change Background Colour of Dashing List Widget

Tags: css, dashing

I'm really struggling trying to change the background image of the sample List widget in dashing. I want to be able to set a status = 'Warning' and the have the background change colour.

All the examples are for a number widget not a list.

Comment: Do you have any code? How do you expect us to help?

Comment: Well i am just using the sample buzzwords list.

I have added 
status = 'Warning
send_event('buzzwords', { items: buzzword_counts.values, status: status })

This is added to the rb file. What I am not sure on is how to set up the HTML

Answer (score 0):

See this https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/issues/24.

The steps apply to any widget. You need to send a 'status' to the list widget.